# Is the count function exact in mongo

Tags: mongodb

Is count() in mongodb exact for many documents or is it an approximate number and if it's not is there any function that returns the exact number?

Comment: Is there any reason for you to suspect that it is not exact?

Comment: Why do you question it? Have you seen something or experienced something that makes you question it?

Comment: Sounds like you don't really trust the technologies that you're using :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an exact count. If it were not an exact count, the documentation would reflect that.

> Counts the number of documents in a collection.

Reference - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/count/

Comment: From what I've experienced, during a bulk upsert operation, consisting of about 50K upserts, the count tends to show more records than there actually is (db.col.find.count), but as soon as the bulk operation's over, the count gets back to the normal behavior, showing fewer, consistent number of records. I've seen this behavior on WiredTiger.

Answer (score 2):

if your mongodb is version 4.0.3 or higher, use this for accurate count:

db.collection.countDocuments({})

According to the latest document count() function is inaccurate in case of unclean shutdown or etc, and will be deprecated.
Check this out:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/